# JQuery : Datatable is not showing data properly after scrolling the table

Tags: ajax, datatables, infinite-scroll, server-side-rendering

I have an application wherein I want to show table as a card list layout i.e. the each record/row would be a separate card and 3 such cards should be displayed in a row.I also want an infinite scroll with server side rendering.

scenario:
total records are 105 and the length of the records is 30 but after scroll, it renders blank area and after 2nd/3rd draw the cards are displaying again.

Please find example below.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('preInit.dt', function (e, settings) {
        let api = new $.fn.dataTable.Api(settings);
        api.page.len(30);
    });
    var dtable = $('#paginatedTable').dataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "searching": true,
        "deferRender": false,
        "order": [[0, "asc"]],
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/users/paginated/mysql"
        },
        "scrollY": '300px',
        "scroller": {
            " loadingIndicator": true,

        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "id" },
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "salary" }
        ],
        "createdRow": function (row, data, index) {

            if (data.id) {
                $('td', row).eq(0).addClass('text-left position-absolute l-0');
                $('td', row).eq(1).addClass('text-right position-absolute r-0');
                $('td', row).eq(1).addClass('alert-danger');
            }

        },

    });

    $('#search').on('keyup', function () {
        dtable.fnFilter(this.value);
    });
    $("#sortingId").change(function () {
        dtable.fnSort([0, $("#sortingId").val()]);
    });
    $("#sortingName").change(function () {
        dtable.fnSort([1, $("#sortingName").val()]);
    });

});
```

Screenshot:
[Failure Scenario-above mentioned scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Wcvk.png)
[working scenario-if there is only one card in a row, scrolling is working fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGouR.png)